# Where can I find the description documents of these metrics?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics

Where can I find the description documents of these metrics?
example:

```
alertmanager_cluster_pings_seconds_sum
apiserver_request_total
certificate_depth
```

Are there metrics documents to explain?
I'don't know where to get it.

Comment: Exposed metrics should be described by the exporter or target that you fetch the metrics from. Where do you fetch your listed metrics from?

Comment: @weibeld I fetch these in apiserver:6443/metrics. There are some notes but no detail. I wonder if there will be a separate detailed document？

Answer (score 0):

As @weibeld said in a comment you should find metrics' description in the target that you fetch them from. By now, please find description of metrics that you are looking for:

- [alertmanager_cluster_pings_seconds](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/commit/f146e344e6624c2e73923729cf8f17fd6a397df5) - histogram of latencies for ping messages.
- [apiserver_request_total](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/kube_apiserver_metrics/) - accumulated number of apiserver requests broken out for each verb API resource client and HTTP response contentType and code (Only present from kubernetes 1.15 to replace apiserver_request_count).
- certificate_depth - current depth of workqueue - certificate.

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: Thanks for @abielak . I fetch these in apiserver:6443/metrics. There are some notes but no detail. I wonder if there will be a separate detailed document？